# Concat Date and Time of two DateTime values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two datetime values like A="2014-04-28  00:00:00.000" and B="2014-05-04  04:25:21.340".

And I am expecting the result "2014-04-28 04:25:21.340", that is,the value consisting of the date part from A and time part from B. 

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT A + CAST(B as TIME)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33443)

Answer (score 1):

@m hasan's answer is correct. If you can't guarantee that the time portion of A will be zero:

(SQL Server 2008 onwards:)

```
declare @A datetime = '2014-04-28 00:00:00.000'
declare @B datetime = '2014-05-04 04:25:21.340'

select cast(cast(@a as date) as datetime) + cast(@b as time)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33445)

Comment: what would be the solution , if it is < sql server 2008?